# CentOSでAtomの起動時に「ライブラリが見つからない」とエラー表示される

Tags: centos, atom-editor, yum

CentOS7でatomエディタを起動したいのですが上手くいきません。

ルートディレクトリで下記のコマンドを実行しました。

```
# wget https://github.com/atom/atom/releases/download/v1.18.0/atom.x86_64.rpm
# yum localinstall atom.x86_64.rpm  -y
# atom

エラー 
/usr/share/atom/atom: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

次に下記のコマンドを実行しましたが、変わりませんでした。

```
# yum install libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
```

どなたか起動方法をご教授いただけませんか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: [こちら](https://qiita.com/one-kelvin/items/07bf9b99288e8ecfa4a2)にもありますが、`libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0` を提供しているパッケージは `gtk2`ですね。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yum install`で引数に指定するのは**パッケージ名**です。atom起動時にエラーで表示されているのはライブラリの**ファイル名**なので、該当のファイルがどのパッケージに含まれているのかを([yukihane](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/2808/yukihane)さんがコメントしたリンク先の通り)確認しながら追加インストールしていく必要があります。

(以下はRHEL5での実行結果なので、細かなバージョン番号等は異なる可能性があります)

```
# yum whatprovides libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
gtk2-2.10.4-30.el5.x86_64 : The GIMP ToolKit (GTK+), a library for creating GUIs for X
...
```

`gtk2`パッケージに含まれていることが分かりましたので、`yum install`でパッケージ名として指定します。

```
# yum install gtk2
```

Comment: コメント、回答ありがとうございます。提示していただいたurlを参考に試してみたところ上手くいきました。ありがとうございました。